# p:treeNode element is not getting displayed in primefaces

Tags: primefaces, treenode

My requirement is to display the tree node element in the xhtml page.
But the element is not displayed.

Here is the code

test.xhtml

```
<p:tree selectionMode="checkbox" >    
<p:treeNode>  
        <h:outputText value="Have a nice day "/>  
 </p:treeNode>
<p:treeNode>  
        <h:outputText value="Good Morning"/>  
 </p:treeNode>
</p:tree>
```

Comment: change *selectionMode="checkbox"* to *selectionMode="single"*

Comment: Thanks for your reply....
but that didn't work :(